# Django Python SyncDB SQL

Tags: python, sql, database, django, django-models

I am working on setting up a Django project with a few different apps, but I'm having problems adding the [django classifieds ap](https://github.com/saebyn/django-classifieds) to my other app structure. When I run syncdb, only the models.py from app 1 and 2 are being created in my database, not the tables for the classifieds app. When I visit the page it reads

```
DatabaseError at /create
(1146, "Table 'mydb.classifieds_pricing' doesn't exist")
```

Because the tables are not being created by syncdb. Any ideas for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `classifieds` is in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`